# route traffic throught openvpn

Tags: openvpn, traffic

Before I ask my question, let me clarify for dear moderators that I've searched a lot for a solution, but none of the questions/answers on Askubuntu (and other Stackexchange sites) addresses my problem.

I've set up openVPN on a Debian server and also on my Ubuntu host, and now I'm trying to route all traffic (except DHCP) at client-side through openVPN tunnel. I read almost all guides on the Web with no success. I read [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/13.10/serverguide/openvpn.html), [this](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#redirect), [this](https://forums.openvpn.net/topic14682.html), [this](http://allanmcrae.com/2013/09/routing-traffic-with-openvpn/), [this](http://www.unix.com/ip-networking/133401-help-route-all-traffic-through-openvpn-road-warrior-surf-web-anonymously-safely.html), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541161/redirect-gateway-def1), [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1798849), [this](https://wiki.debian.org/OpenVPN), [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-setup-and-configure-an-openvpn-server-on-debian-6), and some other guides and articles. And none of them resolved the porblem. If I use **`redirect-gateway def1`** command at my `client.conf` (or push it from server-side (`server.conf`)), at client-side I cannot resolve domain names to IPs (basically DNS queries fail), but I can ping public (valid) IPs e.g. Google's DNS server (from my client host).

Here is my server.conf:

```
proto udp
port 1194
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert myserver.crt
key myserver.key
dh dh1024.pem
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
duplicate-cn
keepalive 10 120
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
log         openvpn.log
verb 3
```

And here's my `client.conf`:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote x.x.x.x 1194
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
mute-replay-warnings
ca ca.crt
cert client1.crt
key client1.key
ns-cert-type server
comp-lzo
verb 3
redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dns bypass-dhcp
```

On the server side, I also issued the following command (to NAT the incoming openVPN traffic):

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Here are the [log](http://pastebin.com/czuAd1CW) and [openvpn-status.log](http://pastebin.com/ZWpJ6fEx).

**UPDATE:**

If I use te following command at server side (redirecting DNS queries) mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541161/redirect-gateway-def1), the problem gets resolved (apparently), but how can I make sure that the traffic is going through the VPN link?

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i tun+ -p udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 8.8.8.8
```

Comment: Nobody knows any solution?

Comment: Yes, is there any workaround?

Comment: @AdeMalsasaAkbar There must be, but apparently nobody has touched this area.